# Clickable acronyms with package {glossaries-extra}

Tags: acronyms, glossaries-extra

I'm using the package `glossaries-extra` to define my acronyms. They appear in the short version in the text and the code correctly generates a list of abbreviations. The problem is that I can't click on them. In fact, they do not appear in blue as when one makes a citation with `\cite{}`. Is there anyone who can tell me where I am wrong? The code I am using reads as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{fem}{FEM}{Finite Element Models}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
This is the first time the acronym \gls{fem} appears, so I want to keep it in its long version. This is the second time the acronym \gls{fem} appears, so I want to keep it in its short version. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

- to get clickable entries, the `hyperref` package needs to be loaded before the `glossaries-extra` package. That's one of the few situations in which the `hyperref` package should be loaded before another package, usually it should come after the other packages.
- one needs a place where the click can lead to, e.g. a `\printglossaries`

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{fem}{FEM}{Finite Element Models}
\makeglossaries


\begin{document}
This is the first time the acronym \gls{fem} appears, so I want to keep it in its long version. This is the second time the acronym \gls{fem} appears, so I want to keep it in its short version. 

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]